# dyld: Library not loaded: cv2.so for OpenCV code on Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am newbie to OpenCV as well as Xcode. I want to use OpenCV for which I am checking a basic OpenCV code to display an image. I have changed some of the Xcode settings after which I was able to build this basic code

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Mat img = imread("/Users/mohitagrawal/Desktop/baba.jpg"); //Changepath here.
    if (img.data == 0) {
        cerr << "Image not found!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey();
}
```

But when I run this project, following error is encountered.
"
dyld: Library not loaded: cv2.so
  Referenced from: /Users/mohitagrawal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-feqvdmafymucqibnfkvbscgmyjip/Build/Products/Debug/test
  Reason: image not found
(lldb) 
"
Please help me out.